How is reading in charges compatible with presumption of innocence?
I am a watcher of police bodycam footages, and sometimes I hear that charges are dismissed but read in (especially in Wisconsin) which would mean that they would get onto your record
Doesn't that squash the presumption of innocence because you are given a punishment (a entry on your record) for a crime you haven't been convicted or even tried for?

An entry on your record is not considered a punishment for legal purposes. The same is true of arrest records.

Of course one can argue that the US handling of arrest records, criminal records, mug shots, etc. does violate the rights of those not yet found guilty. This is balanced by the benefits in transparency on police action -- if there is no record, one cannot look for patterns of bias or abuse.

On your record it says dismissed. That is sometimes a good thing. I get your point that sometimes it is not.
